# Writing update queries more efficiently in EE

Tags: database, query

I've got two queries that I'm running separately in a template, one after the other, like this:

```
<?php
  $sql = "UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET status = 'Registered' WHERE channel_id = '12' AND entry_id = {entry_id} AND status != 'Hidden';";
  $this->EE->db->query($sql);
?>

<?php
  $sql = "UPDATE exp_channel_data SET field_id_119 = 'Yes' WHERE channel_id = '12' AND entry_id = {entry_id} AND field_id_119 != 'Yes';";
  $this->EE->db->query($sql);
?>
```

Can someone tell me if and how to write these more efficiently within a single PHP tag/database call please? When I tried running them one after another within a single PHP tag, they failed to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you are performing two queries so you need two calls to the db (if you want to use CI). This is the only other way I could think to do reasonably do it, but it's actually more code (but not handwritten SQL).

```
$this->EE->db->where(array(
    'channel_id' => 12,
    'entry_id'   => $entry_id,
    'status !='  => 'Hidden'
));

$this->EE->db->update('channel_titles', array('status' => 'Registered'));


$this->EE->db->where(array(
    'channel_id'      => 12,
    'entry_id'        => $entry_id,
    'field_id_119 !=' => "Yes"
));

$this->EE->db->update('channel_data', array('field_id_119' => 'Yes'));
```

Comment: Thanks for this Justin. It's good to know how to do this properly using CI (I seem to doing a mix of two ways - I drifted partly into CI as the Query module doesn't support update queries).

Comment: In terms of legibility (easy to see what's going on at a glance) and best practice, this would be your best bet. I can't imagine the performance benefits would be noticeable by using one SQL query instead of two.

Comment: I will just to Ian's comment that all your methods that interact with the database should be in a Model anyway. So I could combine those two functions above in a method in my add-on model class. Call it update_entry() or something and have it perform both calls.

Comment: Some good points here and I think I'm sold about going in this direction instead, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one query instead of two using the sql JOIN:

```
$sql = "UPDATE  exp_channel_titles ct 
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data cd 
ON cd.entry_id = ct.entry_id 
SET ct.status = 'Registered', cd.field_id_119 = 'Yes'
WHERE ct.channel_id=12 AND cd.field_id_119 != 'Yes' AND ct.entry_id={entry_id} AND ct.status != 'Hidden'";

$this->EE->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Bhashkar. That seems like a good way of combining my two standalone queries (I didn't know much about joins!).